# Repeating strings in pandas DF -- want to return list of unique strings

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a bunch of rows of data in a pandas DF that contain inconsistently offsetting string characters. For each Game ID (another column), the two string characters are unique to that Game ID, but do not switch off in a predicatble pattern. Regardless, I'm trying to write a helper function that takes each unique game ID and gets the two team names associated with it.

For example...

`index     game_id
0         400827888
1         400827888
2         400827888
3         400827888
4         400827888
...
555622    400829117
555623    400829117
555624    400829117
555625    400829117`

`index     team
0         ATL
1         DET
2         ATL
3         DET
4         ATL
...
555622    POR
555623    DEN
555624    POR
555625    POR`

Here is my woeful attempt, which is not working.

```
def get_teams(df):
    for i in df['gameid']:
        both_teams = [df['team'].astype(str)]
        return(both_teams)
```

I'd like it to return ['ATL', 'DET] for Game ID 400827888 and ['POR', 'DEN'] for Game ID 400829117. Instead, it is just returning the team name associated with each index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html):

```
print (df.groupby('game_id')['team'].unique())
game_id
400827888    [ATL, DET]
400829117    [POR, DEN]
Name: team, dtype: object
```

For looping use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for i, g in df.groupby('game_id')['team'].unique().reset_index().iterrows():
    print (g.game_id)
    print (g.team)
```

EDIT:

If need find all `game_id` by some string (e.g. `DET`) use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.groupby('game_id')['team'].unique()

print (s[s.apply(lambda x: 'DET' in x)].index.tolist())
[400827888]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What's the best way to iterate through that second column of team lists, then? I've initialized the groupby to a new variable, but can't call the column from that variable.

Comment: def get_teams(df, team):
    for game_id in df['gameid']:
        both_teams = df.groupby('gameid')['team'].unique()
        team_games = []
        for row in both_teams:
            if team in row[1]:
                team_games.append(game_id)
Seems to be an infinite loop, for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, do you need `for g in df.groupby('game_id')['team'].unique():
    print (g)` ?

Comment: No, my fault for the confusion. What I mean is: when I'm iterating through the "(df.groupby('game_id')['team'].unique())" object (once I've initialized it), how do I reference back to the game_id? Say I'm looping through every line in that grouped object... I would like to return the game IDs that fit the criteria of my loop.

Comment: I add solution to answer, please check it.

Comment: It didn't work. I don't want it to print, I want to assign it to a variable and then iterate through that variable.

Comment: Do you want assign values to list?

Comment: I want to assign to a new list only the values that match a certain case -- in other words, I want to check each row for a string, and if that string is in there, I want to return the "Game ID"

Comment: Do you need in output of `(df.groupby('game_id')['team'].unique())` check  which string (e.g.  `DET`) return all `Game ID` , so in sample it return `400827888` ?

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much for your persistence help. Really appreciate it!!